# Termcal lesson numbering

Tags: calendar

I have been using the `termcal` package to produce a calendar for my syllabuses. I like the functionality a lot, but I was wondering if it was possible to make the lesson counting follow more of an outline format than a simple count. So, for example, rather than "1, 2, 3, 4,..." the count could go "1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1,..."

Here is the not-so-minimal working example from the package documentation:

```
\begin{calendar}{9/26/94}{6}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
% Description of the Week.
\calday[Monday]{\classday} % Monday
\skipday % Tuesday (no class)
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} % Wednesday
\calday[Thursday]{\noclassday} % Thursday (unnumbered)
\calday[Friday]{\classday} % Friday
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
% Holidays
\options{10/31/94}{\noclassday}
\caltext{10/31/94}{No Class\\Halloween}
% Exams
\caltext{10/12/94}{Midterm Exam}
% Text on consecutive days
% the subject of the 9th lecture
\caltexton{9}{\S1.2,1.3\\Sorting and disporting}
% the subject of the 10th lecture
\caltextnext{\S1.3,1,4\\Assembling and dissembling}
\caltextnext{}
% the subject of the 12th lecture
\caltextnext{\S9.9\\Tending and rending}
\end{calendar}
```

Comment: It would be really great if you can provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that the community can play with in order to replicate your current output (and improve on it, of course).

Comment: No problem, there you go.

Comment: You can redefine the way the `classnum` counter prints (using `\renewcommand{\theclassnum}{<stuff>\arabic{classnum}}` where you supply `<stuff>`). However, how would you manage the counter change/resetting. That is, what is `1` in `1.2`?

Comment: Well, obviously there would need to be a way to define that, similar to sections in an article. I know this does not fit in with the basic code of the package, which is why I asked a generic question. I suppose I was just fishing to see if anyone else out there in LaTeXland had thought of this before.

Comment: Okay, the answer to your question then is "Yes, you can print the lesson count using a 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.1, ... representation". It just depends on how automated you want this numbering to be, and what the number preceding the lesson count represents.